# Page loaded callback in Gecko view in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, gecko, geckoview

I am evaluating [Gecko view by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) as a potential Webview for displaying HTML pages in my android app. I want a callback mechanism where if Gecko view is unable to load the page, I should be able to fall back to Android's default Webview or Chrome custom tabs. I was looking into Gecko view's documentation [here](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/) but I can't figure out if Gecko view provides such callbacks or not.

Is it possible to implement such behavior with Geckoview?

Answer (score 1):

There is a page [progress session delegate](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.ProgressDelegate.html) with `onPageStop` which I believe is the same:

```
session.setProgressDelegate(new GeckoSession.ProgressDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStart(@NonNull @NotNull GeckoSession session, @NonNull @NotNull String url) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStop(@NonNull @NotNull GeckoSession session, boolean success) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but `NavigationDelegate` has a `onLoadError` method that is called whenever the page could not be loaded: https://gv.dev/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html#onLoadError-org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession-java.lang.String-org.mozilla.geckoview.WebRequestError-

Example here: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/2f29d53865cb895bf16c91336cc575aecd996a17/mobile/android/geckoview_example/src/main/java/org/mozilla/geckoview_example/GeckoViewActivity.java#1181-1190